# Image to be displayed in one line in pdf from html

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, itext

I use iTextSharp to generate pdf from html. Images are incorrectly displayed. Height of the image is not throwin text. [image]

I create class to get small images

```
public class ImageHander : IImageProvider
{    
  public Image GetImage(string src, Hashtable h, ChainedProperties cprops, IDocListener doc)
  {
   var image = Image.GetInstance(src);
   image.ScaleToFit(500f, 30f);
   return image;
   }    
}
```

And create pdf:

```
PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.GetInstance(doc, new FileStream(FilePath, FileMode.Create));
doc.Open();

Hashtable providers = new Hashtable();
var ih = new ImageHander();

providers.Add("img_provider", ih);

foreach (IElement element in HTMLWorker.ParseToList(
new StringReader(HTMLCode), null, providers))
{       
   doc.Add(element);    
}
doc.Close();
```

Comment: Is the `Html` displaying correctly in browser? what do mean by "one line". Do you want to restrict text overlapping the image?

Comment: Yes, HTML is correctly displayed in my browser.
I do not want the text to overlap the image. New test HTML: <html><head>  <meta http-equiv=\"Content-Type\" content=\"text/html; CHARSET=windows-1250\">   <meta name=\"AUTHOR\" content=\"\"></head><body style=\"color: rgb(0, 0, 0); background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);\" alink=\"#ff0000\" link=\"#0000ff\" vlink=\"#800080\"><p>test</p><img style=\"border: 0px solid ;\" alt=\"\" src=\"file://D:/Images/im0.jpg\"/><p>test</p></body></html>

Comment: I see when is image this code add paragraph with content [OBJ] I think obj is image